# jQuery animate breaks with quick mouse movement!

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

heres a problem of jQuery that has been haunting me for a long time, and I want to finally find a solution. Havng this code:

http://jsfiddle.net/MDfgd/20/

If I move my mouse quickly through all the objects, the animation breaks, as it doesn't unfold completely. How could I do it so that this doesnt happen?

I tried "stop(true, true)", but this makes the animation lose its smoothness, since it jumps to the end of the animation Queue.

Thanks.

Comment: it worked perfectly without .stop() http://jsfiddle.net/MDfgd/22/

Comment: This way it stacks animations...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what he means is that if he moves the mouse over and out in a quick manner, he doesn't want the animations to stack up infinitely. However doing `.stop()` will result in the current animation being stopped instantly, instead of letting the current animation to run its course and removing the *rest* of the animations from the queue. Doing `.stop(true, true)` will jump to the end of the current animation and continue from there.

What the OP wants, I think, is to let the current animation to run through, and after that start the next animation, instead of stacking up the animations infinitely in case of fast mouse movement.

One way to achieve that is to keep track of the currently animating element yourself. This shows one way to achieve what you want:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZrdV6/

**EDIT**

Ok after clarification I made another example. This basically prevents the height from getting messed up by using `stop()` on an element that is being animated by `slideDown()` and `slideUp()`.

The trick is to do the animation yourself with `.animate()`, and to keep track of the original height yourself.

http://jsfiddle.net/YmwZa/1/

Comment: you are right. The problem with the way you described it is that if I go fast in and out the element, the submenu still unfolds completely, and Id prefer if its stops unfolding the moment I make mouseleave

Comment: This works exactly as I wanted! :)

How come "var height = $subMenu.height();" doesnt return "0", if they are in "display: none;" ????

Comment: jQuery changes it to visible for you before it gets the height, and right after that it restores the initial state. This makes it easier for you so you don't have to care about switching it to visible/getting height/hiding it again yourself. In case you're interested in how jQuery does it; it uses `jQuery.swap` to achieve it. Search for a line starting with `swap:` in http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.1.js

Answer (score 1):

I've used `.stop( true, true )` and it seems to work OK.

The animation still looks smooth.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tomgrohl/Pqz9s/

Comment: move quick the mouse between the elements and you will see a jump to the end of the animation queue. I dont want that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little confused about what you mean by "lose its smoothness" - it still looks smooth to me: http://jsfiddle.net/MDfgd/21/

Comment: move quick the mouse between the elements and you will see a jump to the end of the animation queue. I dont want that :(

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("ul.first li").mouseenter(function(){
        $("ul", this).slideDown();
    });
    $("ul.first li").mouseleave(function(){
        $("ul", this).slideUp();
    });

});
```